# Android - Sorting HashMap of and object by one of its fields

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, hashmap

I am building an application that groups users in a recyclerView taking into account the name of the team that the users participate.
So I decided to use HashMap to do this grouping, I get the Id of the team that the users are and I generate a final List to be handled in my adapter.

These are the methods that do this grouping:

```
private HashMap<String, List<UserProject>> groupDataIntoHashMap(List<UserProject> listOfPojosOfJsonArray) {

        HashMap<String, List<UserProject>> groupedHashMap = new HashMap<>();

        for (UserProject pojoOfJsonArray : listOfPojosOfJsonArray) {

            String hashMapKey = pojoOfJsonArray.getTeamId();

            if (groupedHashMap.containsKey(hashMapKey)) {
                // The key is already in the HashMap; add the pojo object
                // against the existing key.
                groupedHashMap.get(hashMapKey).add(pojoOfJsonArray);
            } else {
                // The key is not there in the HashMap; create a new key-value pair
                List<UserProject> list = new ArrayList<>();
                list.add(pojoOfJsonArray);
                groupedHashMap.put(hashMapKey, list);
            }
        }


        return groupedHashMap;
    }
```

Outside the method above I call this:

```
HashMap<String, List<UserProject>> groupedHashMap = groupDataIntoHashMap(ActivityTeams.listUsers);


        for (String date : groupedHashMap.keySet()) {
            TeamItem dateItem = new TeamItem();
            dateItem.setTeam(date);
            consolidatedList.add(dateItem);


            for (UserProject pojoOfJsonArray : groupedHashMap.get(date)) {
                GeneralItem generalItem = new GeneralItem();
                generalItem.setPojoOfJsonArray(pojoOfJsonArray);//setBookingDataTabs(bookingDataTabs);
                consolidatedList.add(generalItem);
            }
        }
```

`consolidatedList` is a List of `ListItem`:

```
public abstract class ListItem {

    public static final int TYPE_TEAM = 0;
    public static final int TYPE_GENERAL = 1;

    abstract public int getType();
}
```

This is my `TeamItem` class:

```
public class TeamItem extends ListItem {

    private String team;

    public String getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(String team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return TYPE_TEAM;
    }
}
```

This is my `GeneralItem` class:

```
public class GeneralItem extends ListItem {
    private UserProject pojoOfJsonArray;

    public UserProject getPojoOfJsonArray() {
        return pojoOfJsonArray;
    }

    public void setPojoOfJsonArray(UserProject pojoOfJsonArray) {
        this.pojoOfJsonArray = pojoOfJsonArray;
    }

    @Override
    public int getType() {
        return TYPE_GENERAL;
    }
}
```

This works perfectly! But the problem is that unfortunately the users that are displayed are not sorted in alphabetical order. So I thought that it would work if I sorted the list before calling the `HashMap` method by doing this:

```
ActivityTeams.listUsers = response.body();
                        Collections.sort(ActivityTeams.listUsers, new Comparator<UserProject>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(final UserProject object1, final UserProject object2) {
                                return object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName());
                            }
                        });
```

Which worked partially because even though the User is being separated into teams and sorted in alphabetical order, the teams are not being shown assorted at all, even after I do this:

```
ActivityTeams.listTeams = response.body();
                        Collections.sort(ActivityTeams.listTeams, new Comparator<Team>() {
                            @Override
                            public int compare(final Team object1, final Team object2) {
                                return object1.getName().compareTo(object2.getName());
                            }
                        });
```

It is important to mention that if the user is not in any team, `getTeamId()` would return null and I should group all of this user in a tab "No team".
So, I would like to know if it's possible to sort the Users and Teams when grouping them when I call the `HashMap`.
And I would like to display the tab "No team" first in my recyclerView.

Comment: Have you considered using a `SortedMap<String, List<UserProject>> groupedHashMap` .... Please be aware that using names as the `key` to a `HashMap` or `SortedMap` can generate an error if you have a duplicate 'Name'.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the reply. I am using the "id" of the team as the key, so there's no risk of having duplicates. 
How would it be the implementation using SortedMap? Would it work if the key is null?

Comment: Your group 'id' is a string? And yes any kind of Map does NOT like null keys.

Comment: Yes, the id is a String, but the HashMap works fine with one of the keys being null.

Comment: Really not a good idea to have 'Null' as a key. I could almost live with a Value being 'Null' but not a key! You might want to rethink your data structure.

Comment: I changed to "-1", now I have null always in front. And I decided to use TreeMap instead of HashMap.
Now my keys look like something like this:
[-1, 59b83da60b616d17065a993a, 59b84145cb49632609e03811, 59a82440cc32316561d803ce, 59c109aa20fe7b48f3832eef, 59a74647cc32316561d7be21, 59c5013b20fe7b48f3871c83]
Each id is related to a name. Do you know how can I sort the TreeMap (by the name of the team) so it would be in alphabetical order?

Comment: Take a look at the documentation for a `SortedMap` https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html  I think it best to use Integer as a map key. If you use a `String` the `SortedMap` will sort alphabetically. BTW, I assumed that above you meant 'Null' and not '0' (Zero).